Deletion of entered characters according to a predefined mask
After replacing the mask with the entered characters, I want to delete the entered characters, but it does not allow me. I can only delete the last one.
I would also like if you think this could be written better, feel free to share an example.
Thanks in advance for your help.
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Masked Input</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class="nb-date-input" data-value="__/__/____" data-date-format="ddmmyyyy">
<script src="demo_dva.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

JS
function dateInput() {
  let inputDate = $('.nb-date-input');
  let maskValue = inputDate.data('value');
  inputDate.val(maskValue);

  inputDate.on('input', function (event) {
    let value = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
    let defaultMask = maskValue;

    value = value.substring(0, 8);

    let newValue = '';
    let inputIndex = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < defaultMask.length; i++) {
      if (defaultMask[i] === maskValue[0]) {
        if (inputIndex < value.length) {
          newValue += value[inputIndex];
          inputIndex++;
        } else {
          newValue += maskValue[0];
        }
      } else {
        newValue += defaultMask[i];
      }
    }

    inputDate.val(newValue);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  dateInput();
});

problem

Masking is tricky, your best bet would be to use a plugin that does it.

Or use a datepicker instead of typing the date by hand.

Or <input type="date">

The problem is that the date entry is a manual type at the client's request. Validation is performed on the client's side. The request was to replace the mask with the entered characters during input and to be able to delete each part of the entered part individually.

So use type="date". This allows manual entry and handles deletion correctly.
